# .innerHTML not working or am I using it wrong?

Tags: javascript

If I understand right, .innerHTML should overwrite whatever was in a certain div or span.
For example:

```
<table width="90%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">

  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="left">Via Email:</td>
    <td width="1070" align="right"></td>
  </tr>

  <script>
  $('#addEmail').click(function()       { 
document.getElementById('emailList').innerHTML = "12345";
  });  
  </script>

      <span  id="emailList">
   <tr>
    <td width="27" align="left"><img src="icon_mail.png" width="24" height="24"></td>
    <td width="228" align="left">123obama@whitehouse.com</td>
    <td align="right"><a href="#" id="dialog_link" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close"></span>remove</a></td>
  </tr>
     </span>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" align="left"><br>
      <input name="input4" type="text" value="vova@kremlin.ru" size="20">      &nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="#" id="addEmail" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-mail-closed"></span>Add Email</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Therefor upon click of #addEmail button, everything inside  would be removed and replaced by "12345".

Yet in reality it doesn't do anything to that span, but just prints out 12345 in the place, where the script is.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually your `span` that's wrong. A span can't ... span (I know, I know) over table rows, so it gets opened and closed somewhere between the rows (or outside the table on some browsers), so when you're overwriting it's html, it ends up somewhere else.

You should name the `tr` instead and overwrite its html, that should work.

Comment: Thanks, putting <tr id="emailList"> seems to work in this case! Yet in what should I be wrapping it, if I might want to add more then one row?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't use `innerHtml` at all, instead I'd name the table and use jQuery's `appendTo` and `insert` methods to add extra rows.

Answer (score 5):

The HTML is [invalid](http://validator.w3.org) — you can't wrap a `<tr>` in a `<span>`. The browser is performing error recovery on your code and producing a DOM that isn't what you expect it to be. When you try to edit the content of the span, the span probably isn't where you think it is.

… you can't put a script between table rows either.

… and you are trying to bind an event handler to a link before the link exists in the document. You either need to move the script so it appears after the link, or move the code that does the work into an event handler that runs after the link exists (such as the `ready` event).

Answer (score 1):

You can't put a `<tr>` inside a `<span>` like that.  Anyway if you're using jQuery, you should probably use its API around ".innerHTML"

```
$('#emailList').html("hello world");
```

That will do some important cleanup work for you. It's not absolutely required, but unless you know for sure what you're doing it's probably a safer option.

Comment: Thanks, putting <tr id="emailList"> seems to work in this case! Yet in what should I be wrapping it, if I might want to add more then one row?

Comment: You just can't hope for things to work out well when you try to wrap table rows in `<span>` tags; it's absolutely not valid markup.  If you need to group rows, you can use `<tbody>` tags, though be prepared for possible weirdness in IE.

Answer (score 1):

You are wrapping a `<tr>` in a span. That is going to lead to unpredictable results. Especially if you then remove the table row.

Comment: It's actually quite predictable, the standard is very clear about it, just not what he thought it would be :)

Comment: @Blindy: I just mean that in my experience different browsers handle this kind of invalidity differently.